# Не работает password_verify()

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Хотел создать систему регистрации и авторизации. Уже всю голову сломал, не знаю в чем проблема.
Версия PHP 5.6
Использовал PDO RedBean

```
        $data = $_POST;
          if(isset($data["do_login"])) { // Проверка нажатия, кнопки входа
            $user = R::findOne('users', "email = ?", array($data['login']));
            if($user){ // Проверка существования пользователя с введенным email
                $valid = password_verify($data['password'], $user->password);
                if($valid){ // проверка пароля
                    echo "Вы вошли";
                }else{
                    echo "Неверный пароль";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Пользователь не найден";
            }

          }
```

Comment: Покажите, что в `$user->password` на момент проверки у вас находится (`var_dump($user->password);` перед `$valid = password_verify(...`).

Comment: В версии 5.6 не работает password_hash and password_verify,
Либо используй md5, либо поменяй версию на более новую.

Comment: @singlesly, да вы фантазер, батенька, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Comment: При 

                    var_dump($user->password);
                    var_dump($data['password']);
                    var_dump(password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

Выходит следующее
string(50) "$2y$10$VGkgkMuLcs8aoPMB2GJAfu0i.Lnnk0r4nFJzuwjDrx." string(6) "123123" string(60) "$2y$10$S7eAFJXJHPQM78U6FkeBqenNm594tiuBCt0ZVQKxpxBTvMMuQCyBW" Неверный пароль

Comment: @BulatKarimov, поле для хеша пароля в базе у вас 50 символов? А должно быть 255 символов, о чем написано в мануале.